# Android Studio MySql PHP JSON error

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm doing a database using Android Studio, but when I try do add something to the database, an error occurs (like a graphical error of some sort) but it successfully adds to the database in phpmyadmin EXCEPT the last column.

My guess is that it has some error in the `addBook` class.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private EditText editTextCurso;
private EditText editTextBibliografia;
private EditText editTextLocalização;

private Button buttonAdd;
private Button buttonView;
private Button buttonMain;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextCurso = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCurso);
    editTextBibliografia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBibliografia);
    editTextLocalização = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLocalização);

    buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonView);
    buttonMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMain);

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonMain.setOnClickListener(this);
}


private void addBook(){

    final String curso = editTextCurso.getText().toString().trim();
    final String bibliografia = editTextBibliografia.getText().toString().trim();
    final String localização = editTextLocalização.getText().toString().trim();

    class AddBook extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Adicionando...","Espere...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
            HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(Config.KEY_EMP_CURSO,curso);
            params.put(Config.KEY_EMP_BIBLIOGRAFIA,bibliografia);
            params.put(Config.KEY_EMP_LOCALIZAÇÃO,localização);

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_ADD, params);
            return res;
        }

    }

    AddBook ae = new AddBook();
    ae.execute();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonAdd){
        addBook();
    }

    if(v == buttonView){
        Button button = (Button) v;
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ViewAllBook.class));
    }
    if(v == buttonMain){
        Button button = (Button) v;
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class));
    }
}
```

Error message when I insert a book:

[image: error]

My php code for addBook:

[image]

Comment: So only 'Localização' fails, if I understood correctly?

Comment: Can you paste addBook.php? It seems like a server side error.

Comment: Yes, only Localização fails....

My addBook.php:

`<?php


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){

 require 'dbConnect.php';

 addBook();

}


function addBook()

{
 global $con;


 $curso = $_POST["curso"];

 $bibliografia = $_POST["bibliografia"];

 $localização = $_POST["localização"];


 $query = " Insert into book(curso,bibliografia,localização) values 
('$curso','$bibliografia','$localização');";

 
 mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error($con));

 mysqli_close($con);


}

?>`

Comment: @MarcosGonçalves this is not where you post code. Edit your OP.
And this might seem really stupid, but I learned back on my C days that using characters like `ç,á,à,ã,etc` as variable name will cause weird errors, sooner or later. I'm not sure if that would still happen on something like Android, but I still think it's good practice to avoid using special characters completely. Try it and run your code again, maybe? Although I don't think that's the problem you're having right now.
anyway, put your php code on your OP so we can help you.